# How are vacant, unreserved Premium Tatkal seats alloted among passengers in the waiting list?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, tatkal

Does anyone know what happens to unreserved seats of Premium Tatkal. Like for a train in evening tomorrow, still 05 seats are left in 3AC against Premium Tatkal and Tatkal 3AC current status is 03 W/L while general quota waiting list is 12 W/L.

I want to ask, that after chart preparation, how will these 05 vacant seats be allotted among tatkal and waiting list/RAC?

Does anyone has any idea?